# Can't load popper.js with Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I recently upgraded to bootstrap 5 and my tooltips/popovers in my application stopped working. I have the following error in console:

[image]

My understanding is that my Laravel Mix / webpack is failing to include popper.js in its compilation? I don't understand why it is looking for popper.js.map, shouldn't everything be compiled into a single file (`app.js`)?

In my `webpack.mix.js` I have:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

In `resources/bootstrap.js` I have:

```
window._ = require('lodash');

try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

and finally in `resources/app.js` I have:

```
window.bootstrap = require('./bootstrap');

require('./components/Job');
require('./components/Toast');
require('./components/Proteomes/ProteomeManager');

var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new window.bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})
```

I have already installed and saved bootstrap and popper via npm. Thanks!

Comment: Try `mix.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css').sourceMaps();`

Comment: Thank you -- the error is gone, but my tooltips still arent working which I imagine is an unrelated problem -- can you explain what .sourceMaps() method does? I read the docs but don't really understand

Comment: It creates a sourcemap file that can be used by browsers/debuggers to "present the reconstructed original in the debugger". Basically a link/reference from your compiled asset (f.e. `public/js/app.js`, which could be minified) to your `resources/js/app.js`, so you know what went wrong in your original file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### in `bootstrap.js`

```
window._ = require('lodash');
import Popper from 'popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js'; 

try {
    window.Popper = Popper; 
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

#### in `webpack.mix.js`

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').sourceMaps();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this ASAP. Can you explain why Popper has to be loaded by referencing a directory in node_modules, and yet lodash, or axios don't need this?

Comment: After installing `npm i @popperjs/core` , if you look inside the `node_modules/popperjs/core` folder you will find  `dist/umd/popper.js` this the file that we like to use.

Comment: Yes, I understand that-- but why is lodash loaded with 'lodash' and not for example 'path/to/lodash.js'? And same with bootstrap? I should note that this was a boilerplate source file included with my Laravel installation so I didn't actually write much of it

Comment: Look inside loadsh folder there is no dist or any other folder

Comment: Okay, awesome! Sorry I am not at my computer right now so I cannot check such things. My last question-- where is it specified that node_modules/ should be treated as the root directory to search for these packages? Thanks again!!

Comment: It depends on the specific package documentation